# Set the HTTP status code from an IOperationInterceptor in OpenRasta

Tags: http, http-status-codes, openrasta

I've written an `ExceptionInterceptor` that wraps the operation invocation in a `try`/`catch` to have centralized exception handling. What I also want to do is have centralized HTTP status code handling, but I seem to be unable to set the HTTP status code from within my `IOperationInterceptor`. My Interceptor takes `ICommunicationContext` as a dependency and sets its `OperationResult` to e.g. `OperationResult.BadRequest`, but OpenRasta still writes the following to the log:

```
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'OpenRasta.Pipeline.PipelineRunner.RunCallGraph'
    38-[2011-07-08 09:11:37Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor OperationResultInvokerContributor.RunOperationResult
        38-[2011-07-08 09:11:37Z] Information(0) Executing OperationResult OperationResult: type=OK, statusCode=200.
```

I've also tried setting the `IResponse.StatusCode` explicitly, but it has no effect. It seems that because the ResponseResource I want to respond with is a valid resource registered in `ResourceSpace` (though without a URI), the status code is ignored and the regular rendering pipeline thrusts forward thinking "this looks okay".

Why is OpenRasta ignoring my StatusCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging I figured out that you can't override the HTTP status code directly from an `IOperationInterceptor`. Instead, you need to store whatever data you need in the `ICommunicationContext.PipelineData` collection from wherever makes sense in your `IOperationInterceptor` implementation. I, for instance, have the following `BeforeExecute` implementation:

```
public bool BeforeExecute(IOperation operation)
{
    if (operation.Inputs.Count() > 0)
        this.inputMember = operation.Inputs.First();

    return true;
}
```

Setting the inputMember in `BeforeExecute` allows me to retrieve the entity (received via HTTP POST or PUT) via `this.inputMember.Binder.BuildObject().Instance` as well as yielding a new `OutputMember` in the `RewriteOperation` method.

When you have stored all the data you want inside `ICommunicationContext.PipelineData` you can then go on to handle stored data and respond accordingly inside an `IPipelineContributor` implementation. You do this by subscribing to the `After<KnownStages.IOperationExecution>()` event like so:

```
public void Initialize(IPipeline pipelineRunner)
{
    pipelineRunner
        .Notify(RenderOnException)
        .After<KnownStages.IOperationExecution>();
}
```

The `RenderOnException` method looks like this:

```
private static PipelineContinuation RenderOnException(ICommunicationContext context)
{
    if (!context.PipelineData.ContainsKey(ExceptionInterceptor.Key))
        return PipelineContinuation.Continue;

    var interestingDataStoredByTheOperationInterceptorImplementation =
        context.PipelineData["SomeKey"];

    // Set context.OperationResult to something meaningful.

    // Instruct the pipeline to render now
    return PipelineContinuation.RenderNow;
}
```

While this might not be the best way to implement this, it works and ends up making the individual Handler methods thin and focused on the problem they are solving. Instead of returning `OperationResult`s left and right, Handler methods can now throw regular exceptions that my `IOperationInterceptor` implementation will catch and then my `IPipelineContributor` implementation can override the `OperationResult` with an appropriate response.